# My App Only Optimized to Work with Iphone7

Tags: ios

I made an app and it almost done, but I have problem with it. It only optimized with iPhone 7. For example, If I start the app with iPhone 7 plus
the labels and the images move a little bit.

is there any way to let my app works with all kinds of iPhones?
if there is a video to explain that , that will be perfect.

thank you

Comment: This is called "autolayout".

Comment: Google "iOS Adaptive Layout". Trust me, it'll help you.

Comment: Better yet, download the WWDC app, filter on WWDC 2016, and search for Making Apps Adaptive, parts 1 & 2. Spend two hours watching ASAP - it'll yield days of time saved down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use trait classes to set the constraints accordingly. Based on your constraints, your app will layout accordingly on different resolutions of iPhones.